# Renormalisibility and renormalisation flow of the $\phi^4$-theory in Peskin & Schroeder p. 402

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

P&S make a curious remark when they compare relevant & marginal operators to superrenormalizable and renormalizable interaction terms.

I will put it in the context. Under the renormalization flow the "action" $\int {\cal L_{eff}}$" behaves like this:

$$\int d^dx {\cal L_{eff}}= \left[\frac{1}{2}(\partial'_\mu\phi')^2 + C'_{2,0}\phi^2 + C'_{4,0}\phi'^4 + C'_{4,4}(\partial'_\mu \phi')^4 +C'_{6,0}\phi'^6\ldots  \right]$$

where I already used a notation for the coefficients of the $\phi^4$-theory that reflect their transformation behaviour under the renormalisation flow:

$$ C'_{N,M} = b^{N(d/2-1)+M-d} C_{N,M}  \tag{12,27} $$

So they coefficients $C_{N,M}$ change under the renormalisation flow whereas the term $\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)^2$ doesn't (if we are close enough to fixed point). Important: the indices $N$ and $M$ of $C_{N,M}$ show the powers and the number of derivatives of the $\phi$-term of which $C_{N,M}$ is coefficient of.

Now the $b$'s exponent: $$N(\frac{d}{2}-1)+M -d$$
serves at the end of section 10.1 of P&S for the distinction between

$$ N(\frac{d}{2}-1)+M -d \begin{cases}
<0\hspace{1cm}\text{ superrenormalizable } \\
=0\hspace{1.55cm}\text{ renormalizable }\\
>0 \hspace{1cm}\text{ non-Renormalizable } 
\end{cases}$$
interaction terms.

I applied this criterion to the $\phi^4$ term for 2 cases:

1. d<4: Since $4(\frac{d}{2}-1)-d<0$ in this case the $\phi^4$ -theory is superrenormalizable. 
   On the other hand in this case the exponent of $b$ with $b<1$ is negative, therefore the corresponding coefficient $C_{4,0}$ of $\phi^4$ will grow during the flow.
2. d>4:  Since $4(\frac{d}{2}-1)-d>0$  In this case the $\phi^4$ -theory is non-renormalizable. On the other hand in this case the exponent of $b$ with $b<1$ is positive, therefore the corresponding coefficient $C_{4,0}$ of $\phi^4$ will shrink during the flow.

This observation seems strange to me. In case of a superrenormalizable theory the interaction term is growing during the flow and in case of a non-renormalizable theory it is shrinking. Should it not be the other way around ? Thank you for any help.

By the way: my question is not about possible triviality or non-triviality of the $\phi^4$-theory. I think, this post is a more basic question.

Comment: The names come from the pre-Wilsonian era of QFT, when people worried a lot about whether theories were well-defined at high energy scales. Running the RG flow backwards (which is a strange thing to do from a modern effective field theory perspective), non-renormalizable couplings grow in the UV while super-renormalizable couplings shrink.